# Where am I over counting in this actuarial probability question?

Tags: probability

I have the following probability question and solution from the author:

[image]

I attempted the problem using

$P[N = 0] + P[N = 1] + P[N = 2]$.

For $P[N = 0]$, we have $P[N = 0] = (0.35)^2(0.55)^2$.

(The accident happens to none of the 4 drivers)

For $P[N = 1]$, we have $P[N = 1] = 2(0.35)(0.65)(0.55)^2 + 2(0.35)^2(0.45)(0.55)$.

(The accident happens to one of the two men or one of the two women. There are two ways of this happening to each of the genders.)

For $P[N = 2]$, we have $P[N = 2] = (0.65)^2(0.55)^2 + (0.35)^2(0.45)^2 + 4(0.65)(0.35)(0.55)(0.45)$.

(The accident happens to either the two men, the two women, or the accident happens to one of the men and one of the women. The accident could happen to either of the two men and either of the two women.)

The sum is then $$P[N = 0, 1, 2] = (0.35)^2(0.55)^2 + 2(0.35)(0.65)(0.55)^2 + 2(0.35)(0.55)(0.45) + (0.65)^2 (0.55)^2 + (0.35)^2(0.45)^2 + 4(0.65)(0.35)(0.55)(0.45) = .72$$

This doesn't provide the right answer. However, when I change the 4 in the above equation to 2, it does provide the right answer:

$$P[N = 0, 1, 2] = (0.35)^2(0.55)^2 + 2(0.35)(0.65)(0.55)^2 + 2(0.35)(0.55)(0.45) + (0.65)^2 (0.55)^2 + (0.35)^2(0.45)^2 + 2(0.65)(0.35)(0.55)(0.45) = .61$$

Somewhere I am over counting.

Comment: It's a bit confusing the way you deal with the whole problem at least to me. Why don't you use 2 random variables $Χ:$ number of men who have accident and $Y:$ number of women who have accident...? In that case, you may use the binomial distribution and you need to calculate the sum:

$$p=P(X=0, Y= 0) + P(X=0,Y=1) + P(X=0, Y= 2) + P(X=1, Y= 0 ) + P(X=1,Y =1) +P(X=2, Y=0). $$

IMHO, I think this way is more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only coincidence that changing the last 4 to a 2 gives you 0.61. Your solution is incorrect in the case of ${P(N=1)}$. For the case that you have exactly 1 female accident and 0 male accidents you need to square the ${0.35}$. That is your term ${2(0.35)(0.55)(0.65)}$ should be ${2(0.35)^2(0.55)(0.65)}$. Keeping everything in your solution the same and making that correction gives you the correct answer of approximately ${0.6132}$.


As a side note, you could define two random variables X and Y, where X is the number of males having an accident and Y is the number of females having an accident. Then X~bin(2,0.65) and Y~bin(2,0.45). This means the total number of accidents is the sum of two independent binomial random variables. Thus ${P(X+Y = k) = \sum_{i=0}^{k} P(X=i)*P(Y=k-i).}$